# Error Starting Kernel: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Tags: post, anaconda, kernel, csrf, jupyter-lab

I don´t know if this error was caused maybe because I deleted one environment from my anaconda navigator, but every time I try starting jupyter lab (from various environments in anaconda or from the default python installed on my computer) I get this error with every single notebook:

`Error Starting Kernel: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST`

I have tried setting the following configuration to True:

```
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
```

By generating the j`upyter_notebook_config.py` file from Pycharm. I also deleted the `.jupyter` folder but nothing of what I have done works.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to migrate all my files to pycharm :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Reinstalled several time with different option but no success. Jupyter Notebook works just fine